# How can I find on which side of an EdgeCollider2D (Unity 3D) a collision takes place?

Tags: collision-detection, unity3d-2dtools

I have a terrain GameObject with an EdgeCollider2D and a Character GameObject with a Random Collider. I want to find on which side of the EdgeCollider2D the Collision is happening on whenever OnCollisionEnter2D is called. 
I wrote [these 3 functions](http://pastebin.com/4NeHZKH6) to kinda do this, but they are too slow (there is a ~3-frame lag spike whenever my GameObject collides with Terrain) and sometimes imprecise.

Is there any faster and more precise way for me to do this?

I have a small typo on the code at Pastebin, the first function is not supposed to have the 'Alt' at the end...

Example image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xQlq.png).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where-in I had to know which side of the collider is the collision happening from and I'm afraid  after much searching, I figured there was no efficient way of finding that out.

So, what I did was that I attached 4 trigger points (colliders which act as triggers) around my player which once get triggered, call their own separate independent functions. This is how I was able to find out from which side/direction was the collision happening.

Comment: I believe you've misunderstood me. I don't want to know the direction/side of the Player's Collider. Instead, I need the side of the EdgeCollider2D I've mapped onto my 'terrain', with which the Player collides. That way I can, for example, align my Player's rotation with the side of the terrain he's colliding with.

TL;DR I need a faster way of telling the nearest side of an EdgeCollider to a Point(Vector2), which should also be more accurate than my CheckLinePoint function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collision2D.contacts`. It is a `ContactPoint2D[]` and contains all the points on which the incoming Collider2D object touched/Collided at time of collision as well as normal vectors for all those points (incase you want to bounce of the ball along the normal of the collision point).

In most cases it is usually contains single point but it might return multiple points in certain cases for example: a box colliding with another box (while both having 0 rotation) this will result in full face collision and obviously having multiple contact points.